# What public datasets of radiology reports exist?

Tags: data-request

I know about [MIMIC](https://mimic.physionet.org/about/mimic/) database, which includes "imaging reports".

[Here](https://idash-data.ucsd.edu/community/45) you can also find data that includes radiology reports.

I am yet to explore any of these datasets. But from what I understand they are not focused on radiology reports. Are there any others datasets of this type?